# $X$ and $Y$ are two sets and $f:X\to Y$. If $f(c)=\{y;c\subset X, y\subset Y\}$ and $f^{-1}(d)=\{x;d\subset Y, x\subset X\}$, then the true statement:

Tags: functions, set-theory, inverse-function

The following question appeared in [JEE 2005](https://targetbatch.com/question/519628/).

**Question:**

$X$ and $Y$ are two sets and $f:X\to Y$. If $f(c)=\{y;c\subset X, y\subset Y\}$ and $f^{-1}(d)=\{x;d\subset Y, x\subset X\}$, then the true statement is

- A) $f(f^{-1}(b))=b$
- B) $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$
- C) $f(f^{-1}(b))=b, b\subset Y$
- D) $f^{-1}(f(a))=a, a\subset X$

**My Attempt:**

$c$ is a subset of $X$, $y$ is a subset of $Y$. $a$ is a subset of $x$. The shared link has drawn a pic of this situation.

Also, $d$ is a subset of $Y$, $x$ is a subset of $X$.

Since $f^{-1}(d)=x$, we may say $f(x)=d$

And since $a\subset x$, therefore, $f(a)\subset d$

So, option D) is correct. And the similar reasoning can be applied on option C)

But the answer given is only D)

Why is option C) incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean by$ c\subset X$? Is  $ c$ an element or a set??

Comment: The expression $f(c)=\{y;c\subset X, y\subset Y\}$ is less than clear to me

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos I have edited my post. Is it better now?

Comment: @leon.fuchsler I have edited my post. Is it better now?

Comment: I have posted the question verbatim.